# Ireland - what to see there? :)

Tags: ireland, northern-ireland

So, I'm headed next week (on Tuesday) to Ireland for nearly 2 weeks, and I'm going across the country (Dublin - Kilkenny - Cork - Dingle - Galway - Belfast - Dublin) and I'd really like to take my Nikon D5100 with me and take memories of places, where's worth.

Beside Giant's causeway and lakes in central Ireland, what are yours favourite places to see?

I'm taking with me Nikkor 18-105 and 170-300.

Comment: Welcome! Please see the [help] - overly broad and opinion-based questions aren't really for this site - objectively answerable ones are. Hopefully we can help you with some of those, but for now I'm putting this on hold.

Comment: 301 irl://library